# Remove select box on click

Tags: jquery

I can add more select elements when I click on the `+` button. I also want to remove them when I click the `-` button. It should remove one select element if I click `-` once. How do I do this

```js
$(function() {
  var p = 2500;
  $('#add').click(function() {
     $("div").append(' Adult: <select><option>1</option><option selected="selected">2</option><option>3</option></select>');
    $("div").append(' Child: <select><option>0</option><option selected="selected">1</option><option>2</option></select><br>');
    value = $("#rooms").val();
    price = $("#price").val();
    priceInt = parseInt(price);
    value++;
    price = priceInt + p;
    $("#rooms").val(value);
    $('#price').val(price);
    if (value > 0) {
      $('#selectAdult, #selectChild').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
  $('#minus').click(function() {
    value = $("#rooms").val();
    if (value > 0) {
      price = $("#price").val();
      priceInt = parseInt(price);
      value--;
      price = priceInt - p;
      $("#rooms").val(value);
      $('#price').val(price);
    }
    if (value == 0) {
      $('#selectAdult, #selectChild').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
  var adult = $("#selectAdult option:selected").text();
  adultInt = parseInt(adult);
  price = $("#price").val();
  priceInt = parseInt(price);
  if(adultInt == 3){
    price = priceInt + 400;
  }
  $('#price').val(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type = "button" id="minus" value="-">
    <input type="text" id="rooms" value="1" readonly="readonly">
    <input type = "button" id="add" value="+">
    Total: <input type="text" id="price" value="2500" readonly="readonly">
    <div>Adult: <select id="selectAdult">
      <option>1</option>
      <option selected="selected">2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    Child: <select id="selectChild">
      <option>0</option>
      <option selected="selected">1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      </select><br></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also I want to add 400 to the total if the adult selected is 3. I have written the code but I guess that's not how it's done cause it isn't working.

Comment: looks like this is part 2, the part 1 is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897935/how-to-make-the-select-tags-unselectable-or-hidden ? I wonder how many parts there are at all?

Comment: Just 2. Yea I am having a tough time.

Comment: I'm happy to know that there are just 2 parts, the most nightmarish scenario is the number of parts is undefined, something like when scrolling an endless list to see more undone parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change you `append` in add function and wrapped it with `<span>` (you should use class) and in minus function i removed `span` last-child

```js
$(function() {
  var p = 2500;
  $('#add').click(function() {
     $("div").append('<span> Adult: <select><option>1</option><option selected="selected">2</option><option>3</option></select> Child: <select><option>0</option><option selected="selected">1</option><option>2</option></select><br></span>');
    
    value = $("#rooms").val();
    price = $("#price").val();
    priceInt = parseInt(price);
    value++;
    price = priceInt + p;
    $("#rooms").val(value);
    $('#price').val(price);
    if (value > 0) {
      $('#selectAdult, #selectChild').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
  $('#minus').click(function() {
    value = $("#rooms").val();
    if (value > 0) {
      price = $("#price").val();
      priceInt = parseInt(price);
      value--;
      price = priceInt - p;
      $("#rooms").val(value);
      $('#price').val(price);
      $("div span:last-child").remove();
    }
    if (value == 0) {
      $('#selectAdult, #selectChild').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
  var adult = $("#selectAdult option:selected").text();
  adultInt = parseInt(adult);
  price = $("#price").val();
  priceInt = parseInt(price);
  if(adultInt == 3){
    price = priceInt + 400;
  }
  $('#price').val(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input type = "button" id="minus" value="-">
    <input type="text" id="rooms" value="1" readonly="readonly">
    <input type = "button" id="add" value="+">
    Total: <input type="text" id="price" value="2500" readonly="readonly">
    <div>Adult: <select id="selectAdult">
      <option>1</option>
      <option selected="selected">2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    Child: <select id="selectChild">
      <option>0</option>


      <option selected="selected">1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      </select><br></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: This works. But when the value in the input is 0 and then when we try to add a select element. It adds 2 select elements instead of one. Can you fix that.

Comment: I made it work by the its value not being able to go below 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if (value == 0) {
  $('#selectAdult, #selectChild').hide();
}
```